# Flutter Web - set-cookie is not in the response headers

Tags: flutter, web, cookies, flutter-web, dio

I have called an API for login and the cookies from server is there in network section in dev-tools in google chrome. I am attaching the screenshots and the code for reference.
We are using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package for the network.

[image]

***Code***

```
static Future<void> request({
    required HttpMethod? method,
    bool hideLoadingIndicator = false,
    required String? path,
    required Map? params,
    required BuildContext context,
    required OnResponse onResponse,
  }) async {
    try {
      if (!hideLoadingIndicator) {
        showLoading(context);
      }
      Response response;
      switch (method) {
        case HttpMethod.post:
          response = await DioFactory.dio!.post(
            path!,
            options: Options(headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
            }),
            data: params,
          );
          break;
        case HttpMethod.delete:
          response = await DioFactory.dio!.delete(
            path!,
            data: params,
          );
          break;
        case HttpMethod.get:
          response = await DioFactory.dio!.get(
            path!,
          );
          break;
        case HttpMethod.patch:
          response = await DioFactory.dio!.patch(
            path!,
            data: params,
          );
          break;
        case HttpMethod.put:
          response = await DioFactory.dio!.put(
            path!,
            options: Options(headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
            }),
            data: params,
          );
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }

      print("----whole response----->>>>>>>>> $response");
      print("------rawCookies--->>>>>>>>> ${response.headers.map}");

      if (!hideLoadingIndicator) {
        hideLoading(context);
      }

      if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        showSessionDialog(context);
      } else if (response.data["success"] == 0) {
        List errors = response.data['error'];
        if (errors.isNotEmpty) {
          // handleApiError(errors.first ?? "");
          handleApiError(errors.first ?? "", context);
        } else {
          handleApiError("Something went wrong! Please try again.", context);
        }

        // handleApiError(response.data["error"]["message"]);
        // onError!(response.data["error"][0], {});
      } else {
        onResponse(response.data);
        // onResponse!(BaseResponse.fromJson(response.data));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (!hideLoadingIndicator) {
        hideLoading(context);
      }

      String errorMessage = "";
      if (e is DioError) {
        if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
            e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout ||
            e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
            e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
          errorMessage = 'Server unreachable';
        } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
          if (e.response!.statusCode == 401) {
            PrefUtils.clearPrefs();
          } else {
            final response = e.response;
            List errors = response?.data['error'];
            if (errors.isNotEmpty) {
              errorMessage = errors.first;
            } else {
              errorMessage = "Something went wrong! Please try again.";
            }
          }
        } else {
          errorMessage = "Request cancelled";
        }
      } else {
        errorMessage = e.toString();
      }

      handleApiError(errorMessage, context);
    }
  }
```

I am getting this errors and in the Applications tab the cookie is not stored and also not there in the response headers log you can see in the image.

[image]